# Linux Log File Parsing syntax via script

Tags: linux, bash

One of my commands output is:

```
 15 |TotalCount Hour=23 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
 10 |TotalCount Hour=22 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
 21 |TotalCount Hour=21 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
 20 |TotalCount Hour=20 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
 20 |TotalCount Hour=19 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
 22 |TotalCount Hour=18 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
 47 |TotalCount Hour=17 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
 39 |TotalCount Hour=16 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
 44 |TotalCount Hour=15 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
 38 |TotalCount Hour=14 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
```

And when I use this command in a script and assign it's output to X this becomes:

```
 15 |TotalCount Hour=23 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 10 |TotalCount Hour=22 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 21 |TotalCount Hour=21 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 20 |TotalCount Hour=20 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 20 |TotalCount Hour=19 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 22 |TotalCount Hour=18 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 47 |TotalCount Hour=17 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 39 |TotalCount Hour=16 Date=2018-05-29 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 44 |TotalCount Hour=15 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 38 |TotalCount Hour=14 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 28 |TotalCount Hour=13 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 30 |TotalCount Hour=12 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 36 |TotalCount Hour=11 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 50 |TotalCount Hour=10 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 38 |TotalCount Hour=09 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 20 |TotalCount Hour=08 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 6 |TotalCount Hour=07 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263 2 |TotalCount Hour=00 Date=2018-05-30 Result-Code=5001 AVPcode=1263
```

How can get the same syntax in X

Comment: x=`find  -name "0.log" -print  | grep SERVER1 | xargs  sed -n '/^Time/{N;s/\n//;p}'|grep "Failed parsing list"| awk '{print "|TotalCount Hour="substr($3,1,2)" Date="$2 " " substr($23,1,16) " AVP"$44}' |sort -r | uniq -c`

Comment: not helping its the same with j=`find -name "*.Business.0.log" -print  | xargs  sed -n '/^Time/{N;s/\n//;p}'|grep "Failed list"| awk '{print "    " "|TotalCount Hour="substr($3,1,2)" Date="$2 " " substr($23,1,16) " AVP"$44}' |sort -r | uniq -c`

Comment: Quote your variables :) Try: echo “$X”. When you execute: echo $X, then X is expanded and each whitespace separated word becomes an argument to echo, eating newlines in the process.

Comment: `x=$(your_command); echo "$x"` ; #note the double quote on the vairable  in echo command.

Answer (score 1):

You could simple use double quotes `"$x"` with `echo` to get the lines in the variable's value. See these examples.

```
x="here is the first line.
Here is the second line."
```

Now when we print `echo $x`:

```
here is the first line. Here is the second line.
```

Now when we print `echo "$x"` then output will be with new lines as follows.

```
here is the first line.
Here is the second line.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add \\n to the end of your line. The first slash is to escape the second slash and the \n is a new-line character.

Now when you're printing out the variable it's going to print out with new lines like you had it.

Comment: What are you using to print the variable? Don't use echo. Use printf "hello\nworld\n" This should print out hello and world in different lines